# Capitalization of "Gothic" as a genre descriptor

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

In the context of genres such as Gothic literature and Gothic music should "Gothic" be capitalized? Although names of genres are generally not capitalized, these happen to share the name of a historic ethnic group. My confusion comes from the fact that these genres have essentially no connection to the Gothic people, so should they still retain the capitalization given to names of ethnic groups?

Comment: Merriam-Webster, for one, says that, in the sense you mention, it is ["often not capitalized."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Gothic) (The examples don't make it clear, because they provide sentences that start with the word.)

Comment: A century ago it was almost always capitalised in contexts like ***Gothic** literature*, but [increasingly today it's not.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+Gothic+literature%2Cof+gothic+literature&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20Gothic%20literature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20gothic%20literature%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer.

*Goth band* has overtaken *goth band* in written material- See [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Goth%20band%2Cgoth%20band&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

A BBC article on *World Goth Day* - 22/May use **goth** for the music/bands/kids-in-black-clothes but **Gothic** (capital) for the novels and architecture.

> In 1979 another British band, Bauhaus, released Bela Lugosi’s Dead, which is often cited as one of the first examples of **goth** music. The song title refers to the Hungarian actor who played Count Dracula in the 1931 Hollywood film. It's a song full of eerie noises, and it sounds as if it could have been recorded in a **Gothic** castle.
> Goth music gave rise to a subculture: **goth**. The traditional **goth** image includes black or purple clothes, tons of black eyeliner and dark make-up. Some **goths** dress in lavish faux-Victorian clothes recalling characters from **Gothic** film and literature.
> […].
> ‘Goth’ and ‘Gothic’ have had many different meanings. It is strange to think that a word referring to an ancient population became a way to describe a new and exciting style of literature, film and, eventually, music.
> — [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/articles/z8dwqfr)

Answer (score -3):

Gothic is always capitalized because it refers to the Goth people of central Europe. Even when referencing things like "that Goth chick" it is capitalized. Gothic architecture or Gothic apparel is still referencing the Goth people, though possibly not in an enlightened way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If we follow that logic, a word like sodomite ought to always be written with a capital, but it oughtn't. Do you know what makes this a special case?